# suggestd taking too much memory overnight on 10.14 Mojave

Tags: memory, spotlight, memory-leak

It's not the first time my Macbook wakes up and I find it very slow because `suggestd` took 6-10 Gb of memory out of 16. Only `kill -9` helps.

I have the latest 10.14.6 Mojave. I am not willing to upgrade to 10.15.

In Spotlight settings, only "Applications" and "Settings" are enabled. There is a very limited amount of them, so it doesn't look like `suggestd` is functioning properly.

Can I fix it? If there's no known fix, how do I diagnose what is going wrong?